# Play video in swing (VLCJ without VLC)

Tags: java, swing, dll, vlcj

How can I play a video in swing with the library `vlcj` without having `vlc` installed?

What I have done:

1: Downloaded the `vlcj` library, **vlcj 2.4.1 (zip)** and add all to build path: 
([docs1](http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/downloads/index.html))

2: Downloaded the `libvlc.dll` and `libvlccore.dll` and put them in project folder:
([docs2](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?libvlc))

([docs3](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?libvlccore))

3: Downloaded a sample video from http:([here video](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1425)) and put it in project folder:
**sample_mpeg4.mp43**: ([docs4](http://a1408.g.akamai.net/5/1408/1388/2005110405/1a1a1ad948be278cff2d96046ad90768d848b41947aa1986/sample_mpeg4.mp4.zip))

I then created the following class to show the video in `swing`:

```
public class MediaPlayer extends JPanel {

// Declares our media player component
private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaplayer;
// This string holds the media URL path
private static String mediapath;
private JPanel panel;

public MediaPlayer() {
    String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String vlcpath = projectPath;
    mediapath = projectPath + "\\sample_mpeg42.mp4";

    // Check if the .dll is correct
    File f = new File(vlcpath + "/libvlc.dll");
    System.out.println("VLC PATH CORRECT: " + f.exists());

    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), vlcpath);
    mediaplayer = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(mediaplayer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(mediaplayer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void play() {
    mediaplayer.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mediapath);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    JFrame ourframe = new JFrame();
    ourframe.setContentPane(mediaplayer);
    ourframe.setSize(720, 560);
    ourframe.setVisible(true);
    mediaplayer.play();
    ourframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

But getting the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load
>   the native library. The error was "Unable to load library 'vlc':...

Do I need to have something else/more then the `libvlc.dll` and `libvlccore.dll`?

Comment: Yes, you need all of the plugins that actually decode and play video and audio of course...

Answer (score 2):

A typical VLC installation on Windows goes in "Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC".

In that directory you will find libvlc.dll and libvlccore.dll.

You will also find a "plugins" directory with a lot of sub-directories containing shared libraries for video/audio decoding and playback, as well as other things like LUA support, media meta-data support, service discovery, the vlc GUI, and so on.

You need those shared libraries too.

In principle you do *not* need *all* of those shared libraries, you just need the ones required to play your media (you may not be interested in LUA for example, nor the vlc GUI so you could remove those).

In practice, the difficulty is in working out precisely which sub-set of the shared libraries you need (there's no definitive list describing which plugin is needed for which purposes) so I expect most people just redistribute all of them.

You do need to be careful what you redistribute, because while most of the VLC plugins are now licensed under LGPL, not all of them are.

Comment: Got the impression that vlcj were one of the best swing players to deal with. But seems a bit large.. Guess I need to check which plugins I need. But still same error after placing the "plugin" folder in my project folder... Any hint on what to try?

Comment: Install vlc and use that first rather than downloading a couple of DLLs from some unofficial site. Once you have it working with an installed vlc, it should be easy enough to package up the DLLs however you want. If not, then get this working first: http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/tutorial1.html

Comment: Whatever you copy to your project folder must match the exact same directory structure as what is in the vlc installation folder. You then must point the native library search path for JNA to the directory containing libvlc.dll. This *does* work...

Answer (score 0):

Minor addition to the answer by caprica. I moved VLC folder contents to {project.dir}/lib folder, removed everthing except dll files and plugins folder. I still faced the exception with an output "**Vlc plugin error, No plugins found**". I found as issue [here](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx/issues/12), which mentions that new jna version included in vlcj versions 3.10.0+ messes with VLC plugin loading.

Solution: either include vlcj version 3.9.0 as a dependency, or as I did, pull the vlcj source from github, and in vlcj pom.xml change the jna.version from 4.1.0 to 3.5.2, run 'mvn clean install' and use this local vlcj artifact in your project with this version(to avoid confusion in the future between local repo and maven repo, change vlcj version to 3.xx.xx-custom or similar, so local artifact will be used always).

In the code, add custom path like this:

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "./lib");
```